# net c# lock statement in data access layer

Tags: c#, locking, data-access-layer

I saw a code where they have the data access layer like this:

```
public class CustomerDA{  

    private static readonly object _sync = new object();  
    private static readonly CustomerDA _mutex = new CustomerDA();  

    private CustomerDA(){  
    }

    public CustomerDA GetInstance(){    

        lock(_sync){      
            return _mutex;        
        }    
    }  

    public DataSet GetCustomers(){  
        //database SELECT
        //return a DataSet
    }  

    public int UpdateCustomer(some parameters){  

        //update some user
    }

}  


public class CustomerBO{  

    public DataSet GetCustomers(){  

        //some bussiness logic  
        return CustomerDA.GetInstance().GetCustomers();
    }
}
```

I was using it, but start thinking... "and what if had to build a facebook like application where there are hundreds of thousands of concurrent users? would I be blocking each user from doing his things until the previous user ends his database stuff? and for the Update method, is it useful to LOCK THREADS in the app when database engines already manage concurrency at database server level?"

Then I started to think about moving the lock to the GetCustomers and UpdateCustomer methods, but think again: "is it useful at all?"

**Edit on January 03:**

you're all right, I missed the "static" keyword in the "GetInstance" method.

Antoher thing: I was in the idea that no thread could access the _mutex variable if there was another thread working in the same data access class. I mean, I thought that since the _mutex variable is being returned from inside the lock statement, no thread could access the _mutex until the ";" was reached in the following sentence:

`return CustomerDA.GetInstance().GetCustomer();`

After doing some tracing, I realize I was making the wrong assumption. Could you please confirm that I was making the wrong assumption?

So... Can I say for sure that my Data Access layer does not need any lock statement (even on INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) and that it does not matter if methods in my DataAccess are static or instance methods?

Thanks again... your comments are so useful to me

Comment: Wherever you saw that code, don't ever look there again. This is simply bad code. Ignore it.

Comment: I think the one who wrote the code meant to have a singleton of CustomerDA.  The lock at GetInstance() isn't really necessary because _mutex is readonly.  You won't be blocked when you are running the SQL statements because there is no lock at GetCustomer() and UpdateCustomer().

Answer (score 2):

The lock in that code is completely pointless. It locks around code that returns a value that never changes, so there is no reason to have a lock there. The purpose of the lock in the code is to make the object a singleton, but as it's not using lazy initialisation, the lock is not needed at all.

Making the data access layer a singleton is a really bad idea, that means that only one thread at a time can access the database. It also means that the methods in the class have to use locks to make sure that only one thread at a time accesses the database, or the code won't work properly.

Instead, each thread should get their own instance of the data access layer, with their own connection to the database. That way the database takes care of the concurrency issues, and the theads doesn't have to do any locking at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with much of this. There are quite a few assumptions. A singleton for a DAL doesn't mean it can't use a connection pool to allow multiple threads concurrent connections. Not to mention the code doesn't look transcribed properly. GetInstance() should be static but isn't. They either thought the lock would only allow one user access to the database, or it used to be a incorrect implementation of Double-Checked Locking to ensure only one instance was created ever.

Comment: @Andrew Finnell: Yes, a singleton class with a connection pool would also work, but from the description in the question it doesn't sound like there is anything like that at present.

Answer (score 0):

Set your lock where it is needed, so where concurrent accesses happen. Put in only as much code inside lock/critical section as much really need.

That GetInstance shouldn't be static ?

the following pseudo code explains how GetInstance operates:

1. LOCK
2. rval = _mutex
3. UNLOCK
4. Return rval

_mutex is readonly, refers to a non-null object, so it can't be changed, why lock ?

If your database provides concurrency management, but in your program you create two thread writing the same data in the same time in your own domain while waiting for the data,
how could your database help ?

Comment: What do you mean with the last part of your answer (how could database help if there are 2 threads writing same data at the same time)? So, is it a good idea if I take the lock to the method level? something like: "public int UpdateCustomer(){lock{ //some code here }}"

Comment: Do not think in this way :"I am locking things always here". For example if you want to use only one connection to database due to memory spare purposes, you have to lock only that statements, which are using that connection, not others. Always sink the locks to as deep function level as you can, and do not lock statements, that can run in the same time. "public int UpdateCustomer(){ /*local computings*/ .. lock{ /*using global variables, calling non-thread safe functions of global objects, etc. */ } /*more local computing*// } }"

Comment: So again in general: narrow locks as much as possible! if you think you cant go deeper, ask yourself which statements would cause interference in that function call. then go inside that function, and repeat. you will reach a point (like file.write(a) and write is in a library), when you cant narrow more. you see the point ? this is a good tactic to avoid some deadlocks, cause you release immediatly locked objects, so noone have to wait for an unnecessary lock). this 3 thing must strictly follow each other: 1)LOCK 2)GET_DATA_FROM_LOCKED 3)UNLOCK_IMMEDIATELY

Comment: Ok, I removed the lock from the GetInstance method, and I understand that I can take the lock to the UpdateCustomer level when needed... Do you think that "Making the data access layer a singleton is a really bad idea"? Should I remove the singleton and return a new instance each time? or maybe I should remove instances at all and call static methods like "CustomerDA.GetCustomers()"?

Comment: Static and singleton in your case is equal. The reason we prefer singleton is that its lifetime is simpler to handle, and avoiding satic/global data as much as possible makes your code easier to maintain. If you want to store informations about every connection, like username,password,time of connection,permission, etc., then use new instances. I wouldn't say that using a singleton as data access layer is always a bad idea, but if you want to think about the future and to make modifications later in your code, then separate the database accessor and the client data.

Comment: This is a good way to go: Create lightweight connector object for every new request. From these objects call the singleton methods, which handles the connections to the database, therefore you can limit for example the maximum connections. If you know memory pools, this singleton would do something similar like those. With this solution you can also easily use more databases in the same time. The clients should not know about the structure of the database, from their point it can be either a text file, an MDB file or an SQL database, put the database handling inside the singleton.